# Using column header and values from one dataframe to find weights in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables that look like the following

```
    ID  param1  param2  param3
0  A12       2       1       1
1  B15       1       2       1
2  B20       2       2       1
...
```

and

```
    parameter  value  weight
0      param1      1      10
1      param1      2      13
2      param2      1      21
3      param2      2      39
4      param3      1      49
5      param3      2      61
```

What's the best way to take the first dataframe, lookup each parameter's weight in the second dataframe and return a dataframe like the following?

```
    ID  param1  param2  param3
0  A12      13      21      49
1  B15      10      39      49
2  B20      13      39      49
```

What I was thinking was to write a function given the parameter, and value, subset table2 like the following, 
`table2[(table2['parameter'] = parameter) & (table2['value'] = value)]` and doing some kind of vectorized application to each column in table1, but Im not sure how to go over each value and do the lookup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to transform `table1` to long format, merge with `table2` on parameters and values, and then transform it back to wide format:

```
In [85]: pd.merge(pd.melt(df1, id_vars='ID'), df2,
                  left_on=['variable', 'value'], right_on=['parameter', 'value']
                   ).pivot('ID', 'parameter', 'weight')
Out[85]:
parameter  param1  param2  param3
ID
A12            13      21      49
B15            10      39      49
B20            13      39      49
```

Answer (score 2):

A bunch of thrashing about and I came up with something far inferior to @Psidom.  I only convinced myself to post to provide some insight into getting at the same solution with varying techniques.

```
In [55]: (df1.set_index('ID')
             .rename_axis('parameter', 1)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(name='value')
             .merge(df2)
             .set_index(['ID', 'parameter']).weight.unstack())
Out[55]:
parameter  param1  param2  param3
ID
A12            13      21      49
B15            10      39      49
B20            13      39      49
```